# How will JQuery impact Web development?

Tags: jquery

JQuery is a hot topic these days.  Today, on Stack Overflow, there are currently [8,470 questions with the JQuery tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) making it the 10th most popular topic - right up there with SQL.

In selecting a new skill to learn and master, I imagine most developers want something useful that lasts.  No developer wants to learn something that is all hype today and full of disappointment tomorrow.

My question to the Stack Overflow community is how will JQuery impact Web development over the next few years?

- Will Web developers still be using JQuery?
- Will most Web developers understand what JQuery is?
- Will JQuery be a necessary skill for all Web developers?

I know there will be some temptation to be subjective in your responses but I'm really looking for evidence to suggest that JQuery is more than just hype.  As an example, the fact that [Microsoft added support for JQuery in Visual Studio 2008](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/28/jquery-and-microsoft.aspx) says alot.

Other relevant information might include the number of large companies using JQuery, the number of job postings for JQuery, articles depicting reduced development time with JQuery, the stability of JQuery since its introduction, etc..

Comment: I think of jQuery as just a library.  A library that you can use to build fantastical stuff, but also its plain JS that is needed to use it. Other than that, its research, RTFM, and practice that get you more experience with jQuery.  I haven't seen any jobs that require jQuery, they just require JS knowledge and XHTML capable development.

Comment: "will"? Will nothing - it's already happened.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments - your feedback should be quite helpful to people like me who missed this revolution.

Comment: A revolution would be Microsoft, Mozilla, Apple/Google creating a new standard scripting language for web that had the features of the various libraries and a progression from C#/Java/Python/C++ etc.. This is more of an evolution from Bonobo to Spider Monkey (bom tish)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you're not already using it, or some other form of javascript library you are already so far behind the eight ball in regards to professional javascript web development it's almost laughable.

You're utterly insane if you don't add a javascript framework to your web development repetoire. jQuery is one of the most popular because it's also one of the best and simplest to start with - it will be around for a very, very long time.

**End original answer**

**Addendum**
Ok, so after re-reading my answer I can certainly see how people could see it as rude and for that I apologise - I'm leaving the original answer so people have context. The indication I got from the original question was that the submitter hasn't chosen a framework at all for development and frankly I was fairly shocked that in this day and age people are still trying to hand write the kind of javascript UI interactions clients expect in web development.

Some reasons you need to choose a framework:

- You're killing yourself and your development time if you don't.
- You get to concentrate on the fun bits of development and ignore the incredibly boring compatability bits.
- Ajax is easier

You can get a fairly detailed comparison of various frameworks [here](http://mankz.com/code/GlobalCheck.htm).

Some reasons you should choose jQuery:

- It's a piece of piss to learn
- Very active author
- Good test structure - they test one version ahead (where available) and one behind on all major browsers as well as the current version
- A robust plugin society
- An intriguing [new test environment](http://ejohn.org/blog/test-swarm-alpha-open/) for javascript

Here's the best bit - even if you started learning jQuery tomorrow and it stopped being useful three weeks from now it still wouldn't be wasted knowledge because it's just a framework. By using it you're **still getting better at javascript** and no mater what happens to **any** of the frameworks HTML5 and it's new API based elements guarantee javascript is going to be around for a very time.

On a slight tangent regarding my original answer, I thought it was a little amusing that the first person to complain I was being rude was from Switzerland. I don't think I've ever met a rude Swiss person. Then the next person who commented with a 'What rudeness?' was from New York. Heh - I probably couldn't be rude enough to register with a New Yorker if I spent hours trying to craft the rudest response I could muster (it's not that NY's are particularly rude, I just don't think they notice it when others are).

Somewhere in between those two extremes probably lies everyone else; so for those people who did think I was rude, I apologise and hope this expanded answer helps clarify my original thinking.

Comment: And the rudeness was needed for… ?

Comment: I interpreted it as an enthusiastic response.

Comment: I didn't think I was being particularly rude - rather I was trying to forcefully stress how important it is to just take a leap and try something. Sitting around endlessly evaluating the good and bad of things is pointless if you can spend 5 minutes working with it and know it's a worthwhile adoption. Anyone who's done javascript web development knows jquery is worth using within five minutes of trying to do *anything* with it.

Comment: I don't think there was any rudeness, he said it like it is.

Comment: imho, the OP opened himself up for this kind of response - asking how jquery *will* impact web development is desperately naïve

Comment: I agree with this answer, but you didn't provide any supporting evidence other than "you're utterly insane" -1

Comment: I think Olbaum was referring to phrases like "almost laughable" and "utterly insane". And are other frameworks really "so far behind the eight ball"??

Comment: It was the "almost laughable" part that I found a bit bothering, because it's normal to be behind when planning to learn a new skill. I could have responded differently too, sorry.

I completely agree with the "utterly insane" part, though: my present self said the same thing to my past self very recently.

Aynway, your edited answer is really worth it.

@DisgruntledGoat: I don't think he meant that for the other framework, but rather for not using a framework (whichever it is) at all.

Comment: I think the original jquery redesign image was right, jQuery does make you a rockstar.

Comment: the original response was rather refreshing.

Answer (score 7):

> I know there will be some temptation to be subjective in your responses but I'm really looking for evidence to suggest that JQuery is more than just hype. As an example, the fact that Microsoft added support for JQuery in Visual Studio 2008 says alot.

In that vein, jQuery's "Who's using jQuery" section on their home page has some big names. Google, Dell, Bank of America, Major League Baseball, Digg, NBC, CBS, Netflix, Technorati, Mozilla, WordPress, Drupal...

Comment: Excellent - I was aware of Google but didn't spot the section you referenced.  Spent most of my time in the Documentation section.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

A nice side effect of learning jQuery is improved CSS skills. If your CSS is already strong you'll be productive in jQuery within hours.

Answer (score 4):

JQuery was recently endorsed by Microsoft and will be included in Visual Studio 2010. They wouldn't have turned on the money hose if they thought it wasn't going to be around for awhile.

JQuery is extremely simple and yet powerful which makes it so viable of a solution.

Comment: While jQuery is one of several fantastic JS libraries, this reason is enough to put it over the top for me, as far as longevity.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if jQuery will be used in 10 years, but I'm quite certain that whatever replaces it will look much like it. jQuery has introduced (a subset of) functional programming to the masses, in an easily-digested and obviously useful format. It's superior in almost every way to imperative dom-manipulation.

Look at it this way -- C was once the less popular new language. It became very popular, and eventually waned as superior languages were created. But nearly every mass-market language (C++, Java, C#, D, Objective-C) is heavily influenced by C. Potential future JavaScript libraries will have the same relationship with jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

In short, the 'standard' Javascript set of APIs are terribly inadequate versus technologies like Flash, Silverlight; browsers (read: IE) have been buggy since 1999 therefore [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Moo](http://mootools.net/), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) and so on are necessary for now to fill the gap.

In 5 years time I imagine jQuery will be to the web what CGI and Perl were at the beginning -  or atleast I hope so if I'm still doing it professionally in 2014!. That's no disrespect to jQuery as I think it's infinitely more intuitive than Perl and the CGI:: modules were to develop with.

Anyway to answer the actual questions:

- For the next 2-3 years yes developers will be using it, maybe longer. Hopefully it will become a standard that the big 3 browser engines will agree upon.
- As most people have said, I would guess almost everyone is using jQuery or a similar library to write web applications. If they're not that's because they're stuck in old ways or have been programming in their basement without the internet for 3 years.
- It already is a necessary skill, although its learning curve is really not steep at all particularly if you're use to Fluent interfaces, so it could be taught within a day to most developers. The steepest part is the selectors, which is really just CSS selectors plus bells and whistles.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it will be around for a long time, you can see how popular it is right but you have to also notice it has been around already for 4-5 years.  So it has lasted that long without being "popular", I would say it has a very bright future.

Answer (score 1):

Currently to be an effective web developer, you need skills in at least some of the following:

- HTML,
- XHTML
- JavaScript,
- JavaScript Library (jQuery, Prototype, etc)
- CSS
- XML
- JSON
- XSLT
- PHP
- ASP.NET
- Many more.....

This list is not exhaustive!

Future web development languages for the web will attempt bring together these technologies as much as possible. Even if they do remain distinct, something that allows you to write web pages in one language, and effectively generate the above will be the future.

GWT (Google web toolkit) allows you to write JavaScript in Java, so who's to say something equivalent for C#, PHP, or someother language won't be dominant in future.

Answer (score 1):

I figured I would add a response to help others understand exactly how far JQuery has to go before it achieves the status of "firmly entrenched in development society".  I currently work for a bank and [as discussed in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306146/programming-jobs-in-banking-sector-too-good-to-be-true), banks are not anywhere close to cutting edge.

We only heard about JQuery, prototype, and other JavaScript libraries about a month back when we stumbled upon Stack Overflow.  For our previous projects we relied on .NET and Microsoft's ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit as well as manual coding with JavaScript and CSS.

Obviously we missed the boat but I don't think we were the only ones.  The good news is that if this gets adopted by developers in banks, chances are it's here to stay.  I know that I'll be exploring it further.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think within 10 years jQuery will "reinvent" Javascript. In other words, there will be a new scripting standard - supported natively by browsers - that works in much the same way as jQuery with super-quick DOM traversal and modification.

Heck, maybe the whole of jQuery will be natively supported in the future...

Answer (score 0):

It will impact the future of web development as much as JavaScript will... which is, immensely.

Considering that most apps in the future will be web based, jQuery (or whatever it grows into) will most likely be there as one of many tools to help out with JavaScript development until something better comes along.

Right now it's the best tool we have to tackle browser inconsistencies. Even if browsers all start working the same, I don't see it going away anytime soon because it makes so many task that that would be tedious in pure JavaScript really easy.

Learning jQuery isn't hard though, most time goes into learning JavaScript as a language  and all of its quirks (until they go away) if you want to do anything substantial beyond simple interactivity such as building an app.